# Shiro with LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, shiro

I am trying to validate an user using LDAP but the following settings don't work **(Shiro.ini)**:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
authc.usernameParam = login.username
authc.passwordParam = login.password
authc.rememberMeParam = login.rememberMe

user = co.com.xxx.yyy.filters.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap_server:389
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[java.naming.security.credentials] = ldap_password

securityManager.realms= $ldapRealm
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AllSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy

[urls]
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/login.xhtml = user
/** = user
```

**Autentication method:**

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password));
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object
```

**Frameworks:**

```
Shiro 1.2.3
Mojarra 2.1.7
Primefaces 5.1
JDK 1.7
JBoss 7.1.1
```

What is wrong?

```
08:49:45,489 ERROR [co.com.xxxxxxxx.secxxxxx.user.SecxxxxBB] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-443-5) : org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: LDAP naming error while attempting to authenticate user.
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(JndiLdapRealm.java:303) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at co.com.xxxxxxxx.secxxxxx.user.SecxxxxBB.login(SecxxxxBB.java:109) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JsfActionListener.processAction(JsfActionListener.java:65) [javamelody-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165) [javamelody-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208) [javamelody-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181) [javamelody-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.forumsys.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:136) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1608) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory.createLdapContext(JndiLdapContextFactory.java:508) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory.getLdapContext(JndiLdapContextFactory.java:495) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(JndiLdapRealm.java:375) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(JndiLdapRealm.java:295) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:368) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Does "uid=<username you're trying>,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co" exist in your LDAP server? Can that LDAP entry be read by the same user?

Comment: When I put the username instead of {0} I got an error

Comment: So, does the LDAP entry exist? Can it be read by that user?

Comment: How can I test that? There are other applications using an especific user and running right but using spring, when I put in shiro the specific user it shows me this error: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]. If I put an unknown user I get this error: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]

Comment: Use a LDAP client and connect to the server using uid=...,ou=...,... and password, and look for the entry uid=...,ou=...,...

Comment: Ok, I could connect using JXplorer. Now I have the uid and the ou. What is next?

Comment: Navigate the tree shown in the JXplorer to reach the entry `uid=<username you're trying>,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co` and see if you can select it to see it's attributes. Shiro does this with the same user it tries to authenticate (AFIK), so if you haven't specify the same [DN as username when connecting](http://jxplorer.org/help/Connecting_to_a_Directory.htm).

Comment: Yes, I can select it but it shows the value of only 3 attributes: objectClass, objectClass and ou

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the right entry, it seems that you're looking at organizationalUnit object, and I'm guessing that the two objectClass attributes have values top and organizationalUnit, and that the ou is one of Users or Accounts. So it seems that your LDAP server indeed either does not contain the `uid=...,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co` and you're not logged in as that user or that you are logged in as that user but cannot read the user's entry.

Comment: Sorry, I can see now the user attributes. What can I do?

Comment: Double check everything, if indeed the user you're trying to login as is at `uid=<your user>,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co` and using the LDAP client you can authenticate and see `uid=<your user>,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=aaa,dc=ggg,dc=com,dc=co` and the Shiro configuration is as provided in the question I see no other reason for the `32 - No Such Object` error.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: For example, how to set shiro.ini to connect to this online free server: [LDAP free online test server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

Comment: The ldap manager in my company gave me an user and a password, in the shiro.ini I set the password with the ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[java.naming.security.credentials] key but I haven't set the username in the shiro.ini because I don't know how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64898/discussion-between-johnb-and-zoran-regvart).

Answer (score 1):

As requested a sample of Shiro configuration with LDAP realm:

**src/main/resources/shiro.ini:**

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},dc=example,dc=com
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm
```

**src/main/java/ShiroLdap.java:**

```
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.util.Factory;

public class ShiroLdap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();

        AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = securityManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken("riemann", "password"));

        System.out.println(authenticationInfo);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-ldap-realm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error : `org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: LDAP naming error while attempting to authenticate user.`

Comment: Well that's a surprise. Do you think you could provide the full console log or the whole stack trace, it's kinda difficult to help you without any leads into what the actual error is. You know what, I think you could benefit from reading [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Root exception is Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.forumsys.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect] So are you behind a proxy or firewall that doesnt let you connect to port 389 of ldap.forumsys.com

Comment: ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389 needed to be set to my ldap server: ldap://<myDomainController>:389

Comment: Great example!  Just wanted to add that removing the userDnTemplate line from the ini file changes from distinguished names to Principal - the username becomes a simple email address.

Answer (score 0):

By looking your error details it seems ldap server is refusing the connection. Just to make sure there is no connectivity issue from your local dev environment to the ldap server, please install Jexplorer ( open source ldap browser ) and try to connect using the credentials you have.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift  your content quality up